# mysql view with count of variants

Tags: sql, mariadb

In MySQL (10.5.9) I have a table with columns A,B,C,and D. I need a view that would show me another column E, that would have the count of all rows where A, B, and C are the same, but ignoring D. I would call column E "variants". I'm struggling with trying to figure out how this can be done.

Comment: There is no MySQL V10.5.9, but there is a mariaDB

Comment: yes, sorry this is in MariaDB but I just use that to develop on, production server is 5.9.

Comment: Suggest you make your DEV and LIVE database server the same tool and version. MySQL and mariaDB started out the same, but they are now a few years down the line and now have some big differences. One day you are going to find one and waste time

Comment: Yes, but it's also cool to learn about those differences, so there is that.

Comment: Not cool when you learn about them after moving code to the live server and it does not work. But if you think that cool Raise your foot and take a shot at it

Comment: Of course I always test on a non-production clone and save my feet

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by a, b, c) as variants
from t;
```

Comment: This is beautiful, I got it working, thanks. This is what worked for me: (fileID is the PK column I did not mention, and client = A, CI = B, and Title = C). pv1 is the view. 

SELECT *, 
count( fileID) over ( PARTITION BY client, CI, Title ORDER BY client ) AS variants 
FROM pv1

It does slow down the view (40K records) by a few seconds though.

Comment: @JimWeisbin . . . I don't really understand your comment.  This answers the question that you actually asked.

Comment: the comment was a thank you but also a clarification, count(star) does not seem to work, whereas count(fileID) does. For some reason count(star) gives incorrect numbers. (star=asterisk, for some reason disappears when I type it here))

Comment: @JimWeisbin . . . That would suggest that `fileId` is sometimes `NULL`.  However, nothing in your question describes `fileId`, which is why the comment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: fileID is the primary key and is never null. I didn't mention it in my initial question, because I was trying to simplify it - there are actually about 30 columns and that would have just confused things I think.